# Switch between databases

Tags: database

I was wondering if it is possible to switch between different databases on one Drupal installation.

I have a different DB which another application uses it. Both DB are on the same server (localhost) and I was wondering if it is possible to temporarily connect to that DB in order to READ and WRITE data from/to it, using Drupal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, of course, use the database API that comes with PHP.

To use Drupal's database API, configure your databases as described in [*How to connect to multiple databases within Drupal*](http://drupal.org/node/18429) and use [db_set_active()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_set_active/) to switch between databases.